# Reiterating John 3:16, as in its whole meaning…

Tags: bible, heaven, will-of-god, kingdom-of-heaven

God says in John 3:16, “For God so loved the WORLD.”  Why does God love the world so much? Or the induvial people in it? I find is vaccinating that God loves his people so much. Later in, it says, “That he gave his only son” In this part God sacrificed his only son for his people in the worse way possible death on the cross. So, God not only loves the “World” so much, but he sent his son to save it. After we ruin it by eating of the tree of Good & Evil… But not only did He just sacrifice himself He took the burden of every sin in all existent! After all that, it says, “Whomever believes in him should not perish but have everlasting life” Does this mean we only have to believe in Jesus Christ/God to go to heaven? Also, after all we have done to God, He still loves us and even lets us go to heaven.  Like man God is so loving and full of grace it’s remarkable. 
-Thank you for your time and please help answer the questions I asked or give a comment. God Bless.

Comment: Welcome, Kitty. You may attract answers if you actually ask a question at the start! You ask 3 Qs in your comments, the 3rd one launching into a different topic. Could I suggest that your top line be moved to the start of your comments and your 1st 2 sentences  in comments turned into the main Q, for the top line? The 3rd Q might best be posted separately. Please take the Christianity Stack tour to learn more about us: christianity.stackexchange.com/tour This shows how we are different to other sites. Do persevere with getting the format for Qs correct.

Answer (score 1):

thank you for your questions.  Yes, God is wonderfully merciful, loving, and generous.  He is hurting a lot when his children go astray and hurt themselves, because He wants his children to be happy, but to be happy they have to return to him.  So God sends a rescue mission in the person of Jesus, his only Son.

I'll try to answer your questions now.

> Why does God love the world so much? Or the individual people in it?

The world in John 3:16 means all the people He had created, so yes, all the individuals.  The "world" here doesn't mean earth, although God also loves nature as well (because he creates the universe too !) and at the end of time God will recreate earth to be better than ever !

Why does God love the world?  Same reason why parents love their children: they brought the children into the world and they want the children to have the best lives they can have.

> Does this mean we only have to believe in Jesus Christ/God to go to heaven?

The short answer is YES.  But what does believing in Jesus mean?

Let's say the their child breaks a law (shoplifting, steal car, hurt another child, etc), then parents would have to pay for the damage so the child can come home from the police station.  Of course it costs the parents money and shame, but they want to give the child a new start.  **But what does the child need to do?**  If the child still wants to join gangs and doesn't want to come home, what can the parent do?  So believing in Jesus means you have to stop the rebellion and start trusting your parents again and SHOW the trust by obeying their commandments so you can grow to be the best adult you can be.  You don't have to repay your parents the cost of your upbringing or the damage you have caused, you only have to trust your parents.  It's FREE !  That's what believing in Jesus means.

I hope I answered your questions.  Please ask questions in the comments section.

God bless !